# Ошибка UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 44430-44431: malformed \N character escape

Tags: python

Решил я перекодировать информацию из файла (в кодировке "utf-8") в "unicode-escape", записав перекодированную информацию в другой файл, но столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой, решение которой я так и не смог найти, может быть вы подскажете, как мне быть?
Собсна, вот код:

```
import codecs
with open(r'C:/Users/harbin/Desktop/main.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    f = file.read()
    l = codecs.decode(f, 'unicode-escape')
with open(r'C:/Users/harbin/Desktop/hmm.txt', 'w', encoding='unicode-escape') as d:
    d.write(l)
```

Ну а это полный "лог" ошибки:

[image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Уберите строку `l = codecs.decode(f, 'unicode-escape')`, в конце в файл записывайте просто `d.write(f)`

Comment: Вообще, по смыслу `l = codecs.decode(f, 'unicode-escape')` означает, что вы f декодируете ИЗ кодировки `unicode-escape`. Если у вас текст изначально не в этой кодировке, то в этой операции нет смысла.

Comment: Ага...Понял, буду знать, спасибо вам огромное, вы очень помогли!